# Default value of Statement QueryTimeout on DB2 V9.7.7?

Tags: db2

I tried to find out like what is the default value of Statement QueryTimeout in DB2 V9.7.7???
I googled alot but did not get this specific  information. I found the value is 0 in Db2V9.7.4. I am having hard time to find in verison 9.7.7.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *default* query timeout within the DB2 Server or DB2 Client – DB2 will allow a query to run until completion.

Applications can (optionally) set the [`QueryTimeout`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0057060.html) attribute to control this.  If you are using .NET, you might also check to see if your application sets the `CommandTimeout` property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Question like, When I did like statement.getquerytimeout() with DB2V9.7.4 its giving me value 0 which means no time limit for query execution. So is it commandtimeout value??? If yes then will it be the same for 9.7.7 as well. we have DB2V9.7.4 with JDBC driver. please help

Comment: I tried to find out commandTimeout in my application. The value is 60sec that DB2V9.7.7 is setting. Now the question, is the value 60sec is enough for long running queries??? If so then I dont need to bother about querytimeout..